# Hide four input boxes based on drop down selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to hide four input boxes. When I use `if` and `else` it only hides two boxes. My code is in regular JavaScript but I would be open to a jQuery solution.

```
window.onload = function() { 
    var select = document.getElementById("billing_type"); 
    select.onchange = function() { 
        if (select.value == "2") {
            document.getElementById("secondpuppytable").style.display = "inline"; 
        }
        else if (select.value == "3") {
            document.getElementById("thirdtable").style.display = "inline"; 
        }
        else{ 
            document.getElementById("firsttable").style.display = "none"; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: You have tagged jQuery but the code you have shown is vanilla js. You should remove the jQuery tag or state explicitly in your question that you would be open to a jQuery solution. Also you question is hard to understand, could you try phrasing it and adding more details about what your expected outcome is and what is actually happening.

Comment: I would try hiding everything first in the function then show whats needed based on the value.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct you have a 'state' problem. The state of your tables (which table to show) should change when the selected option changes.

You could implement it like this:
(HTML)

```
<select id="billing_type">
  <option value="0">1</option>
  <option value="1">2</option>
  <option value="2">3</option>
</select>
<div id="firsttable">firsttable</div>
<div id="secondpuppytable" style="display:none">secondpuppytable</div>
<div id="thirdtable" style="display:none">thirdtable</div>
```

Javascript:

```
window.onload = function() { 
  function tableSwitcher(tables) {
    this.tables = tables;
    this.activeTable = tables[0];
  }
  tableSwitcher.prototype.setActiveTable = function (i) {
    this.activeTable.style.display = "none";
    this.activeTable = this.tables[i];
    this.activeTable.style.display = "inline";
  }

  var select = document.getElementById("billing_type"); 
  var tables = [
    document.getElementById("firsttable"),
    document.getElementById("secondpuppytable"),
    document.getElementById("thirdtable")
  ];

  var switcher = new tableSwitcher(tables);   
  select.onchange = function() { 
    switcher.setActiveTable(select.value);
  }; 
}
```

Hope this helps!